# Would there be any changes in polarisation for light that is diffracted by diffraction gratings?

Tags: optics, diffraction

My understanding is that s and p polarisation of light will have a different angle when diffracted by diffraction gratings. In wikipedia it says that "According to the Huygens–Fresnel principle, each point on the wavefront of a propagating wave can be considered to act as a point source, and the wavefront at any subsequent point can be found by adding together the contributions from each of these individual point sources."

Should the point sources on the wavefront have a particular polarisation(as it has an effect on the angle of the diffracted light) and if so how do you determine the polarisation of the diffracted light? Would it be more suitable to use the QED interpretation of diffraction instead as wikipedia does mention that "the Huygens analysis also does not include polarization for light"?

Comment: It'll depend on the grating type: metallic reflectors have index $n = -1$ while transmissive or multilayer dielectric reflectors will have polarization-dependent phase shifts because their index of refraction is greater than 1 .  But you don't need QED; just polarization analysis of the optical materials.